# submit button is not working

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am creating a CMS and I am adding an add page to it.

I have used the following code as my add.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = $_POST['content'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
     $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $content);
     $query->bindValue(3, $time());

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br />


<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="content" name="Content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

My problem is.

**My ADD ARTICLE button only refreshes the page**

it **does not** display a warning that all fields are required as it should and it **does not** add anything to my database like I ask it to. but refreshes the page.

please can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `name="Content"` I think you want it to be `name="content"` instead.

Comment: you are a genius. that worked. Thank you so much. I wish I could give you an up vote. - now when I add content I am getting this error message: PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /add.php on line 18

Comment: And as $_POST['content'] is not set the ISSET fails

Comment: sorted. My mistake $time() should be time() on line 18. just goes to show. 1 small mistake can change everything. thank you for your help.

Comment: You have `$query->bindValue(3, $time());` but `$time()` is not set as an item in your form. I'm not sure if you just need to remove the `$` before `time()`